# Json string aren't being displayed on my jsp page

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

In one of the pages from my project, I have this jquery code, which receive two json strings and should add some fields to my form:

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
    var obj_tipo = jQuery.parseJSON( "${lista_tipos}" );
    var obj_campo = jQuery.parseJSON( "${lista_campos}" );

    var newRow = $('<tr>');
    col_1 = '<td> Tipo: </td>';
    col_2 = '<td> <select name="tipo"> </select> </td> </tr>';
    for(var nome in obj_tipo)
        col_2.append('<option value="'+nome+'">'+nome+'</option>');

    newRow.append(col_1);
    newRow.append(col_2);

    $("table.cadastro").append(newRow);

    col_3 = '';
    for(var nome in obj_campo)
        col_3 += '<tr> <td> '+nome+' : </td> <td> <input type="text" name="'+nome+'" value="'+nome+'" size=20 maxlenght=40> </td> <tr>';

    $("table.cadastro").append(col_3);
});
</script>
```

But nothing is being displayed in my page. I check the developer tool from Chrome, and this is being read by the browser:

```
<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
    var obj_tipo = jQuery.parseJSON( "{"Tipo":[{"id":3,"nome":"gerente"},{"id":4,"nome":"supervisor"},{"id":5,"nome":"analista"},{"id":6,"nome":"tecnico"},{"id":7,"nome":"secretaria"},{"id":8,"nome":"seguranca"}]}" );
    var obj_campo = jQuery.parseJSON( "{"Key":[{"id":1,"nome":"e-mail"},{"id":2,"nome":"cidade"}]}" );

    var newRow = $('<tr>');
    col_1 = '<td> Tipo: </td>';
    col_2 = '<td> <select name="tipo"> </select> </td> </tr>';
    for(var nome in obj_tipo)
        col_2.append('<option value="'+nome+'">'+nome+'</option>');

    newRow.append(col_1);
    newRow.append(col_2);

    $("table.cadastro").append(newRow);

    col_3 = '';
    for(var nome in obj_campo)
        col_3 += '<tr> <td> '+nome+' : </td> <td> <input type="text" name="'+nome+'" value="'+nome+'" size=20 maxlenght=40> </td> <tr>';

    $("table.cadastro").append(col_3);
});
</script>
```

Someone can point me What's wrong with this code?

ps.: the full code for this page is this:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp/usuario/cadastra.jsp

the json string is sent to page from the method 'cadastra' of this class:

https://github.com/klebermo/webapp_horario_livre/blob/master/src/com/horariolivre/controller/UsuarioController.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some major issues with this section of the code (in addition to the issues in Satpal's answer):

```
var newRow = $('<tr>');
col_1 = '<td> Tipo: </td>';
col_2 = '<td> <select name="tipo"> </select> </td> </tr>';
for(var nome in obj_tipo)
    col_2.append('<option value="'+nome+'">'+nome+'</option>');

newRow.append(col_1);
newRow.append(col_2);

$("table.cadastro").append(newRow);
```

You start off well, creating a jQuery object containing a brand new `<tr>` element inside it. That next line just initialises a variable with a string, which is ok so far.

That next line also initialises a variable `col_2` with a string, which is technically okay. Except next you try to call `.append()` (a jQuery function) on it, even though it's not a jQuery object. Even if it were, you'd be appending them to the `<td>`, not the `<select>`, which is what you actually want. You also have a closing `</tr>` tag in `col_2`, which is incorrect; you're not working with HTML strings when you use `.append()` (this seems to be a common misconception), you're working with actual DOM elements - that `<tr>` is already closed the moment it's created.

It should probably look something more like this:

```
var newRow = $('<tr>');
col_1 = '<td> Tipo: </td>';
col_2 = $('<td></td>');
var select = $('<select name="tipo">');
for(var nome in obj_tipo)
    select.append('<option value="'+nome+'">'+nome+'</option>');

select.appendTo(col_2);
newRow.append(col_1);
newRow.append(col_2);

$("table.cadastro").append(newRow);
```

Answer (score 3):

1. You need to use `document` instead of `"document"`. Read
   [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).
2. Also wrap your json string in `''`

Use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var obj_tipo = jQuery.parseJSON('${lista_tipos}' );
   var obj_campo = jQuery.parseJSON( '${lista_campos}' );
 ......
```

Comment: It may be useful to explain *why* they need to use single quotes rather than double quotes for wrapping the JSON string, just in case it's not immediately obvious.

Comment: thanks by the answer. I did the fixes you suggest, but the fields still don't be displayed on my page. maybe there is some error in the part of the code where I append the html tags?

Comment: @KleberMota, See Anthony Grist answer He has very well pointed out mistakes which I missed